# How do I change the Z-depth property in Google Polymer when I hover over my element?

Tags: jquery, css, polymer, shadow-dom

The code below is my attempt to change the Polymer Z-depth of a paper shadow element when a user hovers over the paper-shadow element. However this doesn't work and I'm not sure why, not that I expect it to work.

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-animated-pages/transitions/hero-transition.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-image/core-image.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
<polymer-element name="chip-card">

    <template>
        <style>
        #paper_shadow{
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px ; 
            color: white;
        }
        #chip_body{     
            height: 400px; 
            width: 300px; 
            background-color: aqua;
            color: black;
        }
        #chip_top{
            background-color: deeppink;
            background-image: url(http://www.lirent.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Android-Lollipop-wallpapers-p-800x500.png);
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #chip_bottom{
            background-color: #fbfbfb;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%; 
            position: relative;
        }
        #chip_bottom h1{
            font-size: 2em; 
        }
        #chip_bottom p{
            font-size: 1em;

        }

        </style>

        <paper-shadow z="1" id='paper_shadow' bind={{cardShadow}}>

                <div id="chip_body" vertical layout center justified>
                    <div id="chip_top" flex>

                    </div>
                    <div id="chip_bottom">
                        <content select="#chip_bottom"></content>

                    </div>
                </div>

        </paper-shadow>


    </template>

        <script>

        Polymer('chip-card',{

            cardShadow : function(){
                this.setZ = 4;
            }



        });

      </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setZ()` is a function and it belongs to the `paper-shadow` element.

First declare event handler bindings for the mouse events:

```
<paper-shadow z="1" id="paper_shadow" 
    on-mouseover="{{raise}}" 
    on-mouseout="{{lower}}">
```

Then call `setZ()` on the `paper-shadow` element in the handler functions like so:

```
raise: function(){
  this.$.paper_shadow.setZ(4);
},

lower: function(){
  this.$.paper_shadow.setZ(1);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. This makes a lot of sense now that I see it. Now I'm going to try and figure out a slow transition between 1 and 4. Thanks again!